# Нужен алгоритм для разбора списка с середины, чтоб выводил в порядке заданном числами в ячейках. Мой код не выводит оставшиеся ячейки. Благодарю Вас!

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(6);

        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
            int a = 0;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                a = list.get(list.size() / 2 - 1);
                list.remove(list.size() / 2 - 1);
            }
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                a = list.get(list.size() / 2);
                list.remove(list.size() / 2);
            }
          //  if(i == list.size()-1){i--;i--;}
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

Comment: Ну и соответственно список может быть любого четного размера.

Comment: Ничего не понятно из вашего вопроса. Возможно имеет смысл его переформулировать, добавить примеров на входе и выходе, отформатировать код, чтобы его можно было прочитать и понять.

Comment: Да, простите вывод должен быть 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: а мой код выводит 1,2,3,4. Я пробовал применить закомментированный фрагмент, выводит все ячейки но падает с ошибкой IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода на C#, на java сами переведете - тут ничего сложного нет.

```
var list = new[] {6,4,2,1,3,5,7};

int midToStart = list.Length / 2 + list.Length % 2 - 1;
int midToEnd = list.Length / 2;


while(midToStart >= 0 && midToEnd <list.Length)
{
    if (midToStart == midToEnd){
        Console.WriteLine(list[midToEnd]);
    }
    else{
        Console.WriteLine(list[midToStart]);
        Console.WriteLine(list[midToEnd]);
    }
    
    midToStart--;
    midToEnd++;     
}
```

Comment: Премного Вам благодарен tym32167! Вот этого фрагмента"list.Length % 2 - 1", мне как раз и нехватало !

Comment: Уважаемый tym32167! Вы все правильно поняли! Все подошло! Еще раз спасибо !

Comment: @ФедорВерещагин если вам ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой, она слева от ответа.